# Why params can't be used in LIMIT statement in an UDF?

Tags: google-bigquery

Why the following code is not working?

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION udf(max INT64) AS (
  ARRAY(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(["foo","bar"]) LIMIT max)
);
SELECT udf(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT  requires use of literal integer

To resolve this for above query you can use below workaround

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION udf(max INT64) AS (
  ARRAY(SELECT item FROM UNNEST(["foo","bar","bar2","bar3"]) item WITH OFFSET WHERE OFFSET < max)
);
SELECT udf(2)
```